# How to push the correct configuration data with C# worker service to swarm/kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, swarm

I have 3 configs in service:

```py
1 - appsettings.development.json
2 - appsettings.testing.json
3 - appsettings.production.json
```

And i have 3 launch settings for them as well in `launchsettings.json`:

```json
{
    "profiles": {
        "DevelopmentDockerProfile" {
            "commandName": "Docker",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "development"
            }
        },
        "ProductionDockerProfile" {
            "commandName": "Docker",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "production"
            }
        },
        "TestingDockerProfile" {
            "commandName": "Docker",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "testing"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i can normally run service, using correct configuration only on local machine.

I can not push `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable with service when publishing.

Is there any way to bind environment variable to `publishProfile.pubxml` or whatever else, that environment variable `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` will magically appear in docker service on host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

No, there is no such option.

### Longer one

First of all, you can easily set environment variables using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("name", "value")`. But that's probably not what you want.

What you might want is to configure environment variables in configs for container/orchestration tool you use, either set in docker command line (`docker run -e VARIABLE_NAME=value`) or in `docker-compose.yml` for Docker Compose or in service YAML config for k8s.